# ASP.NET MVC5, How to save form state to retrieve it after redirecting?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project in which i have a form to register item's order for one customer. 
I make a button on the form to redirect user to create a "new customer".
After user create his new customer, i want to redirect him to the order's form with the same state he had. I don't know if I have to use session or store data on client side.
I hope you understand me.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: One solution could be to use an modal/popup for your "new customer" form, that you save in ajax, then you would just have to set your customer Id in your order form, to have it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am agree with you but the final user want to able to access from a smartphone the web application. So, I think the modal/popup will overcrowd the tab

Comment: Well, it can be a problem, yeah, it depends on the length of you customer form but customers are used to that now. Anyway, if you don't wan't to use that, I would recommend you to store your order in a database, I found that it's not a good practice to overload your session with complex objects. It should only store Ids and small properties.